# Using template function for generic input validation

Tags: c++, validation, c++11, templates

I want to create a function that will loop until a user enters the correct input type. I'm new to using templates, but I imagine if I want to validate a general type then a template function would be the correct tool to use. I want the function to keep asking the user to enter an input until the type matches the model type.

So this is my attempt so far (which throws an error: 'input': undeclared identifier)

```cpp
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T check_input(T model_input, string message)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        cout << message << endl;
        T input; // will it make the input type the same type as model input used in the arg?
        cin >> input;
        // if valid input then for loop breaks
        if (cin.fail())
        {
            // prompts that there was an error with the input and then loops again
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "Invalid input, please try again" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return input; 
}
```

usage:

```cpp
string model_type = "exp";
string exp_name = check_input(model_type, "Please enter the experiment name:");
```

Will having the unused model parameter force the input variable to be of the same type?
(also is this bad programming practice to have an unused parameter?)

Is there a more elegant way to write a general validation check loop?

EDIT: Why is the undeclared identifier error occurring on line with "return input;"?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem as required here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've added when I call the function, is this now satisfactory?

Comment: I don't understand this use case. Is it always `T == string` or can `T` be something different?

Comment: @ThomasSablik T could be an integer or double for example

Comment: not sure if this actually is the question, but you do not need the unused parameter, you just cannot use template parameter deduction then, you'd need to call it as `check_input<string>("please enter the name");`

Comment: @user463035818 Yeah I have now implemented this thanks to the user melpomene's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which throws an error: 'input': undeclared identifier

That's because `input` is defined inside the loop, but your code tries to use it outside (`return input;`).

Possible fix:

```
    for (;;)
    {
        cout << message << endl;
        T input;
        if (cin >> input) {
            return input;
        }
        // handle input errors
        ...
    }
```

> Will having the unused model parameter force the input variable to be of the same type?

Yes. There is only a single `T` template parameter, so each instantiation of `check_input` will use the same type for its first argument and return value.

Template type deduction will use the type of the first argument to determine `T`.

> (also is this bad programming practice to have an unused parameter?)

Yes. You could just leave it out and call the function as

```
auto exp_name = check_input<string>("Please enter the experiment name:");
```

Instead of relying on type deduction from an (otherwise unused) argument, just have the user pass the type directly.

Comment: You can also `auto exp_name = check_input<decltype(model_type)>("Please enter the experiment name:");`

Answer (score 0):

You return `input` outside of the `for` loops scope, while you are declaring it inside.

Just move the declartion outside of the loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T check_input(T model_input, string message)
{
    T input; // will it make the input type the same type as model input used in the arg?
    for (;;)
    {
        cout << message << endl;
        cin >> input;
        // if valid input then for loop breaks
        if (cin.fail())
        {
            // prompts that there was an error with the input and then loops again
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "Invalid input, please try again" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return input; 
}

int main () 
{
    string model_type = "exp";
    string exp_name = check_input(model_type, "Please enter the experiment name:");
}
```

See live demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/659f82ae8c4ccfda)